# What does '@[A-Z]@' pattern mean in $number = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $password);?

Tags: php, regex

I am new to Php starting working with regular expressions.

I am working on validating the Password input field data tried some other patterns like `preg_match('/^[A-Z]*$/', $password)` but this didn't work for password yet this regular expression is working on e-mail and UserName field.

So searched for the answer on google and got this `pattern('@[A-Z]@')` regular expression and it works fine but i don't understand what is the meaning of @ in this pattern

There are also other validation rules I only mentioned capital letter just to ask about my query...

Comment: `@` is used instead of a more common `/` as a delimiter char.

Comment: The main reason `^[A-Z]*$` "didn't work for password" for you, is that this pattern is anchored at the beginning and end - meaning, the value you are testing must _only_ consist of upper-case letters from start to finish. (Or be completely empty, since this is using the `*` modifier, it would allow for _zero_ characters out of the given class as well.